Novel with a college age protagonist in a world where something is causing people to be violent
I recently read a blurb somewhere about a book involving a college age protagonist. Something happens to make people turn violent (signal, virus maybe?) and he is forced to run. He is trying to get back to his family but doesn't know if they are affected or not. I desperately want to read this book but cannot for the life of me remember where I saw it or any names.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid we'll probably need a few more details to be able to answer this.

Approximately when did you read this blurb? Was it new then?

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HatePlague might be handy.
